# how to create sperate class for ads mob and load and in show in activity?

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to create a separate java class for AdMob how to load and show inactivity in android java.

Comment: please share some of your approaches to get specific help. Also, take a look at the Stack Overflow Guidelines [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post a well formed question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is some idea on how to manage the ads in your application from a central point of view. Here is a sample code below you can try this to create them and control them at one place. similar functions can be created to manage other types as well.

```
 /**
     *  ad manager class managing the ads initializing and showing them 
     */
    class AdManager(context: Context){

        init(){
             MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                    //do something on initialization or leave it as it is
                }
            });
        }

        /**
        *  this function controls showing the xml banner ads
        */
        fun showAd(adView: AdView){
            //some add showing code goes here
            val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
            adView.loadAd(adRequest)
        }

        fun listenForChanges(context: Context, adview: AdView){
                    adview.adListener = object: AdListener() {
                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode : Int) {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                }

                override fun onAdOpened() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                    // covers the screen.
                }

                override fun onAdClicked() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
                }

                override fun onAdLeftApplication() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                }

                override fun onAdClosed() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                    // to the app after tapping on an ad.
                }
        }


        //similar functions can be created and used for other type of ads

    }
```